# Selenium Webdriver testing practice

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have recently started using selenium web driver.Can you please tell me which is the best approach -I have to assert a form with different fields -should i use TestNG class or framework(reading data from  excel).

Thanks

Comment: Hello, please share what you have done and tried yourself

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

As you have recently started using *Selenium WebDriver* the suggestion of *Best Approach* would be entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

However, personally I have found that, starting with a [*Selenium Hybrid Framework*](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/automation-framework-introduction/) i.e. [*reading data from excel*](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-automation-hybrid-framework/) will help you to understand how the core `function()` calls works and a detailed understanding of [*Java Reflection API*](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-reflection).

With the core understanding of [*Java Reflection API*](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-reflection) when you will move towards integrating frameworks e.g. [*TestNG*](http://testng.org/doc/) your understanding of the implemented APIs will be more stronger and implementation will be much more easier.

Comment: Weird. I find my knowledge of Reflection completely unnecessary to working with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is cool way to do random action testing. For example, create a String[] that has all of your non-parameterized page methods (menu clicks, button pushes, typing random text, etc). Select from your array randomly and call something like this:

```
    static public void executePageMethod( YourWebPageClass page, String methodName ) {

        java.lang.reflect.Method method = null;

        try {
            method = page.getClass().getMethod( methodName );
        } catch ( SecurityException e ) {
            Debug( "SecurityException" );
        } catch ( NoSuchMethodException e ) {
            Debug( "NoSuchMethodException" );
        }

        assert (method != null);
        try {
            method.invoke( page );
        } catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
            Debug( "IllegalArgumentException" );
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
            Debug( "IllegalAccessException" );
        } catch ( InvocationTargetException e ) {
            Debug( "InvocationTargetException" );
        }
    }
```

We use this for "wandering user" testing for our web apps.